# Is it possible to restrict the CHANGE fields returned by JIRA API /rest/api/2/search

Tags: search, jira, jira-rest-api, changelog

I am using the API */rest/api/2/search/jql=XYZ&expand=changelog&fields=status* This helps to restrict issue fields to **status**, but changelog contains full change history. But I want to restrict the change log to retrieve only **status** change details to reduce the amount of data returned by API

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to select records from the expanded history, the `fields` param only selects fields from the issue itself, not its changelog. The only way you can reduce the amount of data returned is by making the filter more complex, if you can. Maybe adding filters by created or updated dates, or `status IS/WAS NAME-OF-STATUS` if the status you are looking for is well known. After that, you'll have to process the response and iterate over all history items to filter the ones you need.